# How to broadcast a wifi network with no internet?

Tags: networking

I have a web server running on nodejs on my laptop. I have been testing it locally, by going to http://localhost on my laptop. Now that I am done testing it, I would like to use my laptop (running ubuntu linux) as a web server. In the situations that I will be using the web app, there will be no internet access on either device. I would like to broadcast a wifi network from my laptop, that I can connect to on my iphone, and then have access to my web server on my laptop. You will know what I mean if you have ever used a wireless printer. For example, when I turn on my printer, it creates a wifi network called "HP-Print-LaserJet 1102". When my printer is running, I can go into the wifi settings on my laptop and connect to the wifi network called "HP-Print-LaserJet 1102". I want to do this same sort of thing, and have my laptop broadcast a non-internet wifi network just like a wireless printer. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your laptop's wireless devices supports AP mode:

`iw list`

Under 'Supported interface modes' look for 'AP'.

If it is there, and you are using gnome you can just go to the Gnome Settings Manager -> Wifi -> Settings menu -> Turn on Wi-Fi Hotspot...

By default it will attempt to create a Wi-Fi network with the same name as the current hostname of your laptop.

Any environment with NetworkManager should be simple enough to enable this functionality on, though the GUI interface may vary, or may require command line invocations.